# EFS Encrypted folder questions?

Tags: backup

I have just installed a brand new W2012R2 that includes sensible medical data folders. I was considering Bitlocker but as I need remote access to the server, it will not be a good alternative for me (although I could access the server using iLo from Hp) to enter boot password each time the server is rebooted. Anyway, I have read from EFS and as it can work on the folder level, I have two main questions regarding it:

A) What will happen with scheduled backup tasks that run when the user is not logged-in?. Does EFS work under such scenario?. I understand EFS only decrypts data when you are logged-in (in this case as Administrator). The backup app will do its own encryption so data should not be encrypted.

B) Again, such folders are mounted externally as network shares. Therefore, can they still be accessed from other computers when Admin is not logged-in? (Intuition tells me it does work as we input credentials to access such shares).

Thanks in advance,

Jose